# Any idea how to change the message sent by Digits to confirm the phone number?

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

The default message that is sent by Digits when clicking on the confirmation button is "Confirmation code: ... Enter this code in your app. (Digits by Twitter)".
Any idea how to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Digits doesn't allow you to do it. The only thing you can add in the message is the name of your application. To do so, modify the `Application Name` in the Digits dashboard.